# Jquery Show / Hide Toggle Div Selected Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I would like to show or hide selected items in mobile menu as Toggle.

For example if i click menu toggle. i want to show all the items in Div class sidebar but want to hide content in its child div of it has  .

My menu html for toggle link icon:

```
<a id="pull" class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer">Menu</a>
```

On click menu i want to show all these elements except elements in 
class="sticky"

```
<div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="leftnav">
                  <li>» <a href="#">January</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">February</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">March</a></li>    
                  <li>» <a href="#">April</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">May</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">June</a></li>    
                  <li>» <a href="#">July</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">August</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">September</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">October</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">November</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">December</a></li>
            </ul>
      <div class="sticky">
I dont want to show this item in toggle menu.
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing in doing so?

Comment: set class "sticky" on display:none

Comment: i can show all items in class "sidebar" using jquery but how can i exclude child div sticky from toggle list??

Comment: i want to show class ="sticky" by default on mobile just want to hide from toggle menu. but i want to hide "sidebar" class by default but want to show when click toggle menu

Comment: I want to show every element in class "sidebar" whatever it comes except class sticky as it should be shown by default.

Comment: show your jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
 let $sidebar = $('.sidebar'),
      $btn = $('.toggle');
      
  $btn.click(() => {
   $sidebar.toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
.sidebar{
  display: none;
}

.sticky{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="pull" class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer">Menu</a>
<div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="leftnav">
                  <li>» <a href="#">January</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">February</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">March</a></li>    
                  <li>» <a href="#">April</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">May</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">June</a></li>    
                  <li>» <a href="#">July</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">August</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">September</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">October</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">November</a></li>
                  <li>» <a href="#">December</a></li>
            </ul>
      <div class="sticky">
I dont want to show this item in toggle menu.
  </div>
  </div>
```